1024 point constellation generation faulty(?)
While learning and experimenting, I came across a behavior in GNU Radio that I can't explain:
I can easily generate a constellation with 256 points, but a constellation with 1024 points shows - for me - the wrong behavior. It appears to be asymmetrical.
In any case, it is displayed as such in the 'GUI Constellation Sink'.
To generate the constellation I use the function digital.qam_constellation(256|1024,False,digital.mod_codes.GRAY_CODE,True) both times.
Here is a visualization of these experiments:



Constellation Sink
Flow Graph




Python

DAD_TestQAM.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
#
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Digital->Analogue->Digital
# Author: Th0masRad
# GNU Radio version: 3.8.2.0

from distutils.version import StrictVersion

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ctypes
    import sys
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        try:
            x11 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')
            x11.XInitThreads()
        except:
            print("Warning: failed to XInitThreads()")

from PyQt5 import Qt
from gnuradio import qtgui
import sip
from gnuradio import blocks
import numpy
from gnuradio import digital
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
import sys
import signal
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from gnuradio.eng_arg import eng_float, intx
from gnuradio import eng_notation

from gnuradio import qtgui

class DAD_TestQAM(gr.top_block, Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Digital->Analogue->Digital")
        Qt.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Digital->Analogue->Digital")
        qtgui.util.check_set_qss()
        try:
            self.setWindowIcon(Qt.QIcon.fromTheme('gnuradio-grc'))
        except:
            pass
        self.top_scroll_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.top_scroll_layout)
        self.top_scroll = Qt.QScrollArea()
        self.top_scroll.setFrameStyle(Qt.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.top_scroll_layout.addWidget(self.top_scroll)
        self.top_scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.top_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.top_scroll.setWidget(self.top_widget)
        self.top_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.top_widget)
        self.top_grid_layout = Qt.QGridLayout()
        self.top_layout.addLayout(self.top_grid_layout)

        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "DAD_TestQAM")

        try:
            if StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) < StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry").toByteArray())
            else:
                self.restoreGeometry(self.settings.value("geometry"))
        except:
            pass

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.CONSTELLATION_1024 = CONSTELLATION_1024 = digital.qam_constellation(1024,False,digital.mod_codes.GRAY_CODE,True)
        self.CONSTELLATION_0256 = CONSTELLATION_0256 = digital.qam_constellation(256,False,digital.mod_codes.GRAY_CODE,True)

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x = qtgui.const_sink_c(
            1024, #size
            'Constellation', #name
            2 #number of inputs
        )
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_update_time(0.1)
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_y_axis(-2, 2)
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_x_axis(-2, 2)
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_trigger_mode(qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE, qtgui.TRIG_SLOPE_POS, 0.0, 0, "")
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.enable_autoscale(False)
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.enable_grid(True)
        self.qtgui_const_sink_x.enable_axis_labels(True)


        labels = [' 256-QAM', '1024-QAM', '', '', '',
            '', '', '', '', '']
        widths = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
        colors = ["blue", "red", "red", "red", "red",
            "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"]
        styles = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        markers = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        alphas = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

        for i in range(2):
            if len(labels[i]) == 0:
                self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_label(i, "Data {0}".format(i))
            else:
                self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_label(i, labels[i])
            self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_width(i, widths[i])
            self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_color(i, colors[i])
            self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_style(i, styles[i])
            self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_marker(i, markers[i])
            self.qtgui_const_sink_x.set_line_alpha(i, alphas[i])

        self._qtgui_const_sink_x_win = sip.wrapinstance(self.qtgui_const_sink_x.pyqwidget(), Qt.QWidget)
        self.top_grid_layout.addWidget(self._qtgui_const_sink_x_win, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        for r in range(0, 1):
            self.top_grid_layout.setRowStretch(r, 1)
        for c in range(0, 1):
            self.top_grid_layout.setColumnStretch(c, 1)
        self.digital_constellation_modulator_1024 = digital.generic_mod(
            constellation=CONSTELLATION_1024,
            differential=False,
            samples_per_symbol=4,
            pre_diff_code=True,
            excess_bw=1,
            verbose=True,
            log=False)
        self.digital_constellation_modulator_0256 = digital.generic_mod(
            constellation=CONSTELLATION_0256,
            differential=False,
            samples_per_symbol=4,
            pre_diff_code=True,
            excess_bw=1,
            verbose=True,
            log=False)
        self.blocks_throttle = blocks.throttle(gr.sizeof_char*1, 192000,True)
        self.analog_random_source = blocks.vector_source_b(list(map(int, numpy.random.randint(0, 256, 1000000))), True)



        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_random_source, 0), (self.blocks_throttle, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_throttle, 0), (self.digital_constellation_modulator_0256, 0))
        self.connect((self.blocks_throttle, 0), (self.digital_constellation_modulator_1024, 0))
        self.connect((self.digital_constellation_modulator_0256, 0), (self.qtgui_const_sink_x, 0))
        self.connect((self.digital_constellation_modulator_1024, 0), (self.qtgui_const_sink_x, 1))


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.settings = Qt.QSettings("GNU Radio", "DAD_TestQAM")
        self.settings.setValue("geometry", self.saveGeometry())
        event.accept()

    def get_CONSTELLATION_1024(self):
        return self.CONSTELLATION_1024

    def set_CONSTELLATION_1024(self, CONSTELLATION_1024):
        self.CONSTELLATION_1024 = CONSTELLATION_1024

    def get_CONSTELLATION_0256(self):
        return self.CONSTELLATION_0256

    def set_CONSTELLATION_0256(self, CONSTELLATION_0256):
        self.CONSTELLATION_0256 = CONSTELLATION_0256





def main(top_block_cls=DAD_TestQAM, options=None):

    if StrictVersion("4.5.0") <= StrictVersion(Qt.qVersion()) < StrictVersion("5.0.0"):
        style = gr.prefs().get_string('qtgui', 'style', 'raster')
        Qt.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem(style)
    qapp = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tb = top_block_cls()

    tb.start()

    tb.show()

    def sig_handler(sig=None, frame=None):
        Qt.QApplication.quit()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)

    timer = Qt.QTimer()
    timer.start(500)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: None)

    def quitting():
        tb.stop()
        tb.wait()

    qapp.aboutToQuit.connect(quitting)
    qapp.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


GNU Radio Companion

DAD_TestQAM.grc:
options:
  parameters:
    author: Th0masRad
    category: Custom
    cmake_opt: ''
    comment: ''
    copyright: ''
    description: ''
    gen_cmake: 'On'
    gen_linking: dynamic
    generate_options: qt_gui
    hier_block_src_path: '.:'
    id: DAD_TestQAM
    max_nouts: '0'
    output_language: python
    placement: (0,0)
    qt_qss_theme: ''
    realtime_scheduling: ''
    run: 'True'
    run_command: '{python} -u {filename}'
    run_options: prompt
    sizing_mode: fixed
    thread_safe_setters: ''
    title: Digital->Analogue->Digital
    window_size: (1000,1000)
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [16, 12.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled

blocks:
- name: CONSTELLATION_0256
  id: variable
  parameters:
    comment: ''
    value: digital.qam_constellation(256,False,digital.mod_codes.GRAY_CODE,True)
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [224, 16.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: CONSTELLATION_1024
  id: variable
  parameters:
    comment: ''
    value: digital.qam_constellation(1024,False,digital.mod_codes.GRAY_CODE,True)
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [448, 16.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: analog_random_source
  id: analog_random_source_x
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    max: '256'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    min: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    num_samps: '1000000'
    repeat: 'True'
    type: byte
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [16, 188.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: blocks_throttle
  id: blocks_throttle
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    ignoretag: 'True'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    samples_per_second: '192000'
    type: byte
    vlen: '1'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [296, 216.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: true
- name: digital_constellation_modulator_0256
  id: digital_constellation_modulator
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    constellation: CONSTELLATION_0256
    differential: 'False'
    excess_bw: '1'
    log: 'False'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    samples_per_symbol: '4'
    verbose: 'True'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [552, 124.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: digital_constellation_modulator_1024
  id: digital_constellation_modulator
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    comment: ''
    constellation: CONSTELLATION_1024
    differential: 'False'
    excess_bw: '1'
    log: 'False'
    maxoutbuf: '0'
    minoutbuf: '0'
    samples_per_symbol: '4'
    verbose: 'True'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [552, 268.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled
- name: qtgui_const_sink_x
  id: qtgui_const_sink_x
  parameters:
    affinity: ''
    alias: ''
    alpha1: '1.0'
    alpha10: '1.0'
    alpha2: '1.0'
    alpha3: '1.0'
    alpha4: '1.0'
    alpha5: '1.0'
    alpha6: '1.0'
    alpha7: '1.0'
    alpha8: '1.0'
    alpha9: '1.0'
    autoscale: 'False'
    axislabels: 'True'
    color1: '"blue"'
    color10: '"red"'
    color2: '"red"'
    color3: '"red"'
    color4: '"red"'
    color5: '"red"'
    color6: '"red"'
    color7: '"red"'
    color8: '"red"'
    color9: '"red"'
    comment: ''
    grid: 'True'
    gui_hint: 0,0
    label1: ' 256-QAM'
    label10: ''
    label2: 1024-QAM
    label3: ''
    label4: ''
    label5: ''
    label6: ''
    label7: ''
    label8: ''
    label9: ''
    legend: 'True'
    marker1: '0'
    marker10: '0'
    marker2: '0'
    marker3: '0'
    marker4: '0'
    marker5: '0'
    marker6: '0'
    marker7: '0'
    marker8: '0'
    marker9: '0'
    name: Constellation
    nconnections: '2'
    size: '1024'
    style1: '0'
    style10: '0'
    style2: '0'
    style3: '0'
    style4: '0'
    style5: '0'
    style6: '0'
    style7: '0'
    style8: '0'
    style9: '0'
    tr_chan: '0'
    tr_level: '0.0'
    tr_mode: qtgui.TRIG_MODE_FREE
    tr_slope: qtgui.TRIG_SLOPE_POS
    tr_tag: '""'
    type: complex
    update_time: '0.1'
    width1: '1'
    width10: '1'
    width2: '1'
    width3: '1'
    width4: '1'
    width5: '1'
    width6: '1'
    width7: '1'
    width8: '1'
    width9: '1'
    xmax: '2'
    xmin: '-2'
    ymax: '2'
    ymin: '-2'
  states:
    bus_sink: false
    bus_source: false
    bus_structure: null
    coordinate: [896, 212.0]
    rotation: 0
    state: enabled

connections:
- [analog_random_source, '0', blocks_throttle, '0']
- [blocks_throttle, '0', digital_constellation_modulator_0256, '0']
- [blocks_throttle, '0', digital_constellation_modulator_1024, '0']
- [digital_constellation_modulator_0256, '0', qtgui_const_sink_x, '0']
- [digital_constellation_modulator_1024, '0', qtgui_const_sink_x, '1']

metadata:
  file_format: 1

Unfortunately, the constellations themselves are too large for me to include here. However, you can find all the code, the graphics and the outputs in my Google Drive.
I googled for problems with function digital.qam_constellation() or block digital.generic_mod() (especially with my outdated GNU Radio version 3.8.2.0), but found nothing.
ChatGPT was also at a loss...
I looked up the smallest and largest values of the constellation points and believe they are symmetrical.
Do any of you have knowledge about this behavior and can help me?

the "constellation modulator" block might not be the best tool to test the modulation itself, because it adds pulse shaping, which must inherently "smear" the constellation points, and will be biased if they are not in sufficiently random order; and I'm not sure your sawtooth covers all input cases in a sensible way.

that ChatGPT is "at a loss" is um, the correct description of ChatGPT for any problem. It never understands what it is writing about; it's a random sentence generator trained for generating sentences that might look like sentences that it has seen before. When you ask ChatGPT about a unique problem, it will answer in the tone of someone confident with totally made up nonsense. Don't rely on ChatGPT for anything even resembling understanding of what's happening.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@MarcusMüller #1: I'm aware of the “smearing” of the points, but I don't think it's the cause here - the shift seems too conspicuous to me...
You write that I should not modulate with the “Constellation Modulator”. What do you suggest instead?

@MarcusMüller #2: It's off topic, but [ ;-) ] I like it to get an overview of what I can search for more specifically!

@Community: Thank you, I have drastically reduced the size of my examples!

well, you're still testing something with 1024 points with an input that only ranges 0…255, if I'm not mistaken?

@MarcusMüller: Yes! It is possible that the “Constellation Modulator” cannot process input values >255, but I don't know. There is information on the internet which claims that the “Constellation Modulator” interleaves the incoming bytes, except in a 256 point constellation.
But perhaps the “Constellation Modulator” is limited to the number of bits per symbol and the maximum value of its input data type “Int”.
Who knows ;-)

64 QAM: Byte_1, Byte_2, etc. = Symbol_1 (= 6 bits of Byte_1), Symbol 2 (= 2 bits of Byte_1 + 4 bits of Byte_2), Symbol_3 (= 2 bits of Byte_2 + etc.), etc.
/
256 QAM: Byte_1, Byte_2, etc. = Symbol_1 (= 8 bits of Byte_1), Symbol 2 (= 8 bits of Byte_2), etc.
/
1024QAM: Byte_1, Byte_2, Byte_3, etc. => Symbol_1 (= 8 bits of Byte_1 + 2 bits of Byte_2), Symbol_2 (= 6 bits of Byte_2 + 4 bits of Byte_3), Symbol_3 (= 4 bits of Byte_3 + etc.), etc.

you can know! what about actually trying with a full 0…1024 input instead of speculating?

@MarcusMüller: Unfortunately no, because its input data type is Integer 8, which already collides with the statement that it can process “input values from 0 to 255”... Now I have looked into the Python code: It internally uses the function blocks.packed_to_unpacked_bb(self.bits_per_symbol(),gr.GR_MSB_FIRST). Now I will have a closer look at packed_to_unpacked and try to find out if this function can handle bits_per_symbol > 8.
